# ElasticSearch : how to sort ES document based on document version

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Following is my ES query I want to sort my document in descending order based on "_version" but not sure how to do it

```
{
    "query":
    {
        "bool":
        {
            "must":
            [
                {
                    "terms":
                    {
                        "streamingSegmentId":
                        [
                            "00003319-b7fa-3409-806a-fa3bb5d2be26"
                        ],
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range":
                    {
                        "streamingSegmentStartTime":
                        {
                            "from": 1644480000000,
                            "to": 1647476658447,
                            "include_lower": true,
                            "include_upper": false,
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    },
    "version": true,
    "_source":
    {
        "includes":
        [
            "errorCount",
            "benefitId",
            "streamingSegmentStopTime",
            "fanoutPublishTimestamp",
            "sessionUpdateTime",
            "contentSegmentUpdateTime"
        ],
        "excludes":
        []
    },
    "sort":
    [
        {
            "streamingSegmentStartTime":
            {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        },
        {
            "_version":
            {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I was not able to sort based on _version, hence I added one timestamp field called `fanoutPublishTimestamp` to sort my document in descending order of time. Following is my udpated query and I'm using collapse to fetch only latest timestamp document. Now the recent problem I started facing with following query is collpase cannot be used with search_after. search_after I'm using to add pagination support in my ES query.

I'm using AWS Elastic search which is using 7.10 version of ES and 8.1 ES version only supports collapse with Search_after. Please let me know if anybody has better solution to deal with this issue

```
GET /sessions/_search
{
  "size": 2,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "benefitId": [
              "PRIME"
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "streamingSegmentStartTime": {
              "from": 1647821557000,
              "to": 1647825157000,
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": false,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "deviceTypeId",
      "timeline"
    ],
    "excludes": []
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "streamingSegmentStartTime": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "fanoutPublishTimestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "search_after": [
    "1647821557001",
    "1647829603837"
  ],
  "collapse": {
    "field": "streamingSegmentId"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide your sample documents, and didn't explain what it means that its not working, I am assuming that it's because of two `sort` param you are using, if you use just one `_version` it works(tested locally on my sample documents).

Mostly your another sort criteria `streamingSegmentStartTime` is causing few documents which has higher `_version` to come later in the response, try to remove it and see if it provided you expected result.

Comment: Hi @Amit, thanks a lot for replying here. I was facing ES error on adding _version in sort key. I cannot skip sorting based on streamingSegmentStartTime field. My ES query can return me any number of unique documents, I wanted them to sort first on streamingSegmentStartTime and then on version. I updated the question with What I tried to fix it. Please let me know if you have any other suggestion on the same